# A trouble with Django models and index_together feature

Tags: python, django, django-models

Create a Django project with an app (add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`!) with the following `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class BaseTransaction(models.Model):
    pass

class SubscriptionTransaction(BaseTransaction):
    class Meta:
        index_together = ["id", "canceled"]

    canceled = models.BooleanField()
```

Then the things work this way:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
testprj.SubscriptionTransaction: (models.E016) 'index_together' refers to field 'id' which is not local to model 'SubscriptionTransaction'.
    HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
```

Please explain the reason of this error (there is no multi-table inheritance here) and how to make my code to work.

The problem happens with Django 1.10.3 with both Python 3.5.3 and Python 2.7.13. Is it a Django bug? What's about a workaround?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? `id` is the primary key, so there can only ever be a single record with any value. So including that field in `index_together` makes no sense at all

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right. This code was in error. However this should not allow Django to reject it altogether. Should I report a Django bug?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the id you are using is in other table and this could be generate a lot of problems.

But if you don't need BaseTransaction table you can mark it as abstract, then you can use your index_together perfectly.

```
class BaseTransaction(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without marking it abstract?

Comment: No :( index_together requires that all the fields be in the same table, to sort the data, of this table.